# Instantiating without assigning to a variable

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I'm inheriting the code someone else wrote at work and found that there are a lot of "new" instantiating without actually assigning to a variable:

```
new MyCoolClass().MyCoolMethod();
```

I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience with this and if this is anti-pattern or not.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with it, but `MyCoolMethod` should probably have been a static method instead since the only purpose of the `MyCoolClass` instance is apparently to be able to call the method on it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError true. It might be the case that MyCoolMethod is being used as a proper instance method elsewhere, though.

Comment: To me it is more of an anti-pattern that `MyCoolMethod` seems to cause side-effects on global state. It takes no input and returns nothing. It must read and write global state.

Comment: I guess it's conceivable that the constructor for `MyCoolClass` could persist its `this` pointer somewhere.

Comment: Is the code actually `new MyCoolClass().MyCoolMethod();` or are you seeing it used as `var someVar = new MyCoolClass().MyCoolMethod();`? Also what is the return type of `MyCoolMethod()`?

Comment: sometimes i've had to make a method non-static, when that class implements an interface, and i've wanted to be able to use the method via the interface.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, it **is** really actually `new MyCoolClass().MyCoolMethod()`. The method is an operation and does not return anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you call it often like this, the method should probably be a `static` method, since it seems the instance isn't used or at least relevant. If you create an instance, you should use it.

I would try to write this kind of code out. For performance and understanding.

Comment: How do you know the instance is not used inside the constructor or `MyCoolMethod`?

Comment: You don't, but why care? Why not `MyCoolClass.MyCoolMethod()`?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what the MyCoolMethod() does. If it returns void, then there's no point in assigning it to a variable. I don't know about others, but I use this quite often. Whether or not it's a good practice is up for debate :)

Edit: I agree with @Patrick Hofman. My answer is actually off. I thought OP was asking why we don't have a variable to store what MyCoolMethod() returns. Please see @Patrick's answer :)

Comment: Even if it returns a variable, it doesn't matter. If you create an instance, you should use it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If the methods are doing [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and you only work with the final object from the chain there is no reason at all to keep the initial object around.

Comment: @Scott: then the first should be a `static`, right? And with chaining it has a purpose and it is used, but it looses scope immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor or method uses the instance that is created there is nothing wrong with this. For example the constructor or method may assign values to fields or call other instance methods or pass the instance to another method which uses it. If the instance is truly never used then it's fine to refactor it to a static method like the other answers suggest.

About the assignment, why would you assign the instance to a variable if you don't need to use it again after this one method call? The one reason I can think of is that it might improve readability (or might not) if you give the variable a useful name.